# How to add custom rewrite rule to .htaccess?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I want to add a custom rewrite rule to my `.htaccess` file using a function inside functions.php

The rewrite rule I want to add is as follows:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/author/(.+)$ http://name-blog.com/$1`

I know there is a WordPress function that adds a rewrite rule to the `.htaccess`:

`$wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'mobile/([^/]+)$', 'mobile/index.php?action=$1' );`

So, how can I use that to add my rewrite rule to `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please add your solution as a answer and come back in two days and accept your answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Amereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly) just after posting on the site and this is the code I was looking for:

```
function my_htaccess_contents( $rules )
{
$my_content = <<<EOD
\n # BEGIN My Added Content
# Protect wpconfig.php
<Files wp-config.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
# END My Added Content\n
EOD;
    return $my_content . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
```